# javax's @Valid annotation usage scenario

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

Is it possible to use `@Valid (javax.validation.Valid)` in below scenario?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import com.incident.tool.model.IncidentModel;

@Service
public class JsonStringToObjectConverter {

    public IncidentModel convertToObject(String json) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        @Valid
        IncidentModel incidentModel = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, IncidentModel.class);
        return incidentModel ;
    }
}
```

Here `JsonStringToObjectConvertor` is taking in JSON in form of String and mapping it to `IncidentModel` class. I have defined few validations in `IncidentModel` in below manner and I want to validate the fields mapped by `ObjectMapper` in `IncidentModel` before proceeding further:

```
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class IncidentModel extends IncidentInfo {
    @NotEmpty
    private String empId;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 2, max = 30)
    private String empName;

    @NotEmpty
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String assignedTo;
    private String severity;
    private String incidentNumber;
    private String dateCreated;
    private String dateClosed;
    private String closingNotes;
}
```

It does not seem to work in the above format, is there any alternative to use the `@Valid` in the `convertToObject` method?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something as follows:

```java
@Service
public class JsonStringToObjectConverter {

    public IncidentModel convertToObject(String json) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        IncidentModel incidentModel = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, IncidentModel.class);
        
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<IncidentModel>> errors = validator.validate(incidentModel);
        
        return incidentModel;
    }
}
```

You could then optimize this and make `ValidatorFactory factory` and `Validator validator` instance variables of `JsonStringToObjectConverter` so that you don't recreate them every time you call `convertToObject` method.